# Storing class object in Isolated Storage in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I store object of a class in WP7 Isolated Storage? I want to retrieve it and edit it  whenever required.

Answer (score 5):

You need to serialize your data to save it, then deserialize it to load it. You can find a complete worked example [in this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156254/Simple-Data-Serialization-on-WP7).

For example, mark the class and properties as follows:

```
[DataContract] 
public class Employee  
{  
     [DataMember] 
     public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }  
     [DataMember] 
     public string Name { get; set; }  
     [DataMember] 
     public string Department { get; set; }  
}
```

Construct a serializer:

```
DataContractSerializer mySerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Employee));
```

Then load / save via `ReadObject` / `WriteObject`.

Answer (score 1):

U can use xml serialisation

```
    public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, string fileName)
    {   
     try
      {
        var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, writerSettings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
        }

    stream.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
  }


    public static T DeSerialize<T>(string fileName)
    {
      try
      {
         var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
         IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open);

         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
         return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
    }
```