# save listpicker items to isolated storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, listpicker

I have a list of cities in my settings page.
I want the user to pick a city, and when done, i want the different settings to be saved in isolated storage.
My list:

```
List<Cities> source = new List<Cities>();
source.Add(new Cities() { Name = "Asker", Latitude = "59.83734", Longitude = "10.43595", Datatable = "AskerTable.xml" });
source.Add(new Cities() { Name = "Arendal", Latitude = "58.46151", Longitude = "8.77253", Datatable = "ArendalTable.xml" });
```

How can i write the name of the city, latitude and longitude and name of the table to isolated storage so i can use it in the main page?
How far i have come with the programming of what happens when changed by user:

```
    void listPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
    var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    string fileName="settings.txt";

 using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
         using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
               {
                  writer.Write(listPicker.SelectedItems.);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695821/storing-class-object-in-isolated-storage-in-wp7/10696436#10696436

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the list of objects `List<Cities>` via some serialization format (Xml,Json, etc).  Then write it to the stream.    Then De-serialize it on the way back out when you need it.  I don't know what type the `listPicker.SelectedItems` is but if its just `List<Cities>` that would work...